# Failing to see how this function could be surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove that the function $T : V \to P(F)$ defined by $T(\sigma) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n} \sigma(i) x^i$, where $V$ is the vector space consisting of all sequences over field $F$ that have only a finite number of non-zero terms, is surjective.

I can't see how this could possibly be surjective because we can always choose the polynomial $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$, with each following coefficient being $1$. Then we would have infinitely many non-zero coefficients, so we couldn't possibly choose any sequence in $V$ that could have infinitely many non-zero $1$ terms to satisfy this.

But the question asks to me to prove that it's true, so I'm lost.

Comment: Because that's not a polynomial

Comment: thank you; formality is frustrating